# File renaming and deleting error

Tags: java, file-handling, file-rename

I am trying to modify the data in the file. while checking whether it has successfully deleted and renamed the file,it always prints "Not Successfully changed".

```
public void transfer()
{

    File temp=new File("temp.dat");
    File supply=new File("supply.dat");
    boolean rename=temp.renameTo(supply);
    boolean delete=supply.delete();

    if(delete && rename)
        Sopln("Successfully Changed");
    else
        Sopln("Not Successfully Changed");
}//transfer end
```

here is the switch-case block where i am invoking this method.

```
    Sopln("Modify :-");
    Sopln("1)Preffered Period");
    Sopln("2)Preffered Class");
    Sopln("3)Exit");
    int option;
    do
    {
        option=Check_Int("Enter Your Choice");
        int ctr=0;
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: Sopln("______________________________");
                    String name=Check_String("Enter The Name Of The Teacher Whose Details You Want To Change");
                    String record;
                    while((record=fr.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        String token[]=record.split("-");
                        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(token[0]))
                        {
                            Sopln("Your Current Info:");
                            Sopln("Name : "+token[0]);
                            Sopln("Preffered Period : "+token[3]);
                            Sopln("Enter Your New Preffered Period");
                            token[3]=br.readLine();
                            pw.println(token[0]+"-"+token[1]+"-"+token[2]+"-"+token[3]+"-"+token[4]);
                            ctr++;
                        }//if block end
                        else
                        {pw.println(record);}
                    }//while loop end
                    if(ctr==0)
                    {Sopln("Not Found");
                    submenu();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ctr=0;
                        transfer();
                    }
                    fr.close();
                    pw.close();
                    break;
            case 2: Sopln("______________________________");
                    String name_class=Check_String("Enter The Name Of The Teacher Whose Details You Want To Change");
                    String record_class;
                    int cnt=0;
                    while((record_class=fr.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        String token[]=record_class.split("-");
                        if(name_class.equalsIgnoreCase(token[0]))
                        {
                            Sopln("Your Current Information:-");
                            Sopln("Name : "+token[0]);
                            Sopln("Preffered Class : "+token[4]);
                            Sopln("Enter Your New Preffered Class");
                            token[4]=br.readLine();
                            pw.println(token[0]+"-"+token[1]+"-"+token[2]+"-"+token[3]+"-"+token[4]);
                            cnt++;
                        }//if block end
                        else
                        {pw.println(record_class);}//else block end
                        }//while loop end
                        if(cnt==0)
                        {Sopln("Name Not Found!");
                        submenu();}
                        else
                        {
                            cnt=0;
                            transfer();
                        }//else block end
                        fr.close();
                        pw.close();
                        break;
            case 3: main_menu mm=new main_menu();
                    mm.menu();
                    break;
        }
    }while(option<0 || option>2);
}//change method end
```

so, when I check my documents,the temp file is created with the the necessary modifications but, But the file is not being renamed nor the original Supply file being deleted.
Plz Help!!

Comment: Are you sure file paths are correct?

Comment: What Do You Mean? Didn't Get You

Comment: How you are running this program? from Eclipse or Netbeans IDE, or from CMD? And where are these files are?

Comment: Running these programs from textpad-(pretty basic,not like netbeans)

Comment: Post folder structures, I mean from where you are running programs, where are your class files stored and where are these files in drive?

Answer (score 0):

You 1st to rename and then create a new file variable & then delete. Simple solution.

```
public void transfer()
```

{
    //rename file
    File temp=new File("temp.dat");
    File supply=new File("supply.dat");
    boolean rename=temp.renameTo(supply);

```
//delete file
File f = new File("supply.dat");
boolean delete=supply.delete();


if(delete && rename)
    Sopln("Successfully Changed");
else
    Sopln("Not Successfully Changed");
```

}//transfer end

Comment: The bug it's not inside transfer method

Comment: Wait! It Works! this class is an option of a menu. But if at all i select some other option of the menu then select 'modify' it shows "Not successfully changed".

Comment: Should i edit-print the main_menu and the modify-both the classes?